# DB2 insert rows in tbl1 by id in tbl2

Tags: sql, database, db2

I'm very new to sql and especially DB2.

What I need to do is get all id's from tbl2 and insert new rows in tbl1 using each id from tbl2

I thought of something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl2  (INSERT INTO tbl1 (TID, NAME, ADDRESS) VALUES ( id, 'junk', 'junk'));
```

can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know DB2 but you are heading down the right path.  Normally I would configure it something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (TID, NAME, ADDRESS) SELECT id, 'junk', 'junk' FROM tbl2;
```

And to my knowledge that statement is SQL standard so it should work anywhere that uses the SQL standards ie Oracle, SQL-Server, MySQL, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1(TID, NAME, ADDRESS) 
    SELECT id, 'junk', 'junk'
    FROM tbl2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two Tables
1: Table TBLNewUpdate
2: Table AspNetUsers

I Need TO Insert New Notice For All User With Some Condition.

The Relation Between TBLNewUpdate And AspNetUsers Is
AspNetUsers.Id = TBLNewUpdate.MUserID

```
INSERT INTO TBLNewUpdate(MDate,MAdress, MText,MUserID,MRead)
    SELECT GETDATE(),
    N'Address',
    N'New Text',
    TBUser.Id,
    0
    FROM AspNetUsers TBUser
    WHERE TBUser.EmailConfirmed = 1
```